# Convert DStream[Double,Double] to RDD[(Double, Double)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to train a linear regression model on a streaming data. I read streaming data using `textFileStream`. But the problem is that `RegressionMetrics` accepts `RDD[(Double, Double)]`, while `output` is in format `DStream[Double,Double]`.
How to convert `output` into the `RDD[(Double, Double)]` to be able to use `RegressionMetrics`?

```
val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
      .setInitialWeights(Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0))
      .setStepSize(0.2)
      .setNumIterations(25)

    trainingData = ssc.textFileStream("/training/data/dir").map(LabeledPoint.parse)
testData = ssc.textFileStream("/training/data/dir").map(LabeledPoint.parse)

model.trainOn(trainingData)

val output = model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features)))

val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(output) 
val rmse = metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
```

Comment: where did you define output ???

Comment: @eliasah: Uups, sorry, I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Every DStream consists of an underlying RDD (a separate one for every data batch), which can be accessed using the `foreachRDD` method:

```
model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)
  val rmse = metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
  // do something with `rmse` here
}
```